# Log4j fileapender output out of jar file

Tags: file, jar, log4j

I have a problem related with log4j when I have to do an output file of the logs.

This is my current log.properties file

```
log4j.rootCategory=info, MAIN_LOG

log4j.appender.MAIN_LOG=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.MAIN_LOG.File=log.log
log4j.appender.MAIN_LOG.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.MAIN_LOG.layout.ConversionPattern=$%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}#%p#[%t]#%c#%m#%n
log4j.appender.MAIN_LOG.append=true

log4j.rootCategory=error, A1

# A1 is set to be a LF5Appender which outputs to a swing
# logging console. 

log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.net.SocketAppender
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=$%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}#%p#[%t]#%c#%m#%n
log4j.appender.A1.RemoteHost=localhost
log4j.appender.A1.Port=4712
log4j.appender.A1.ReconnectionDelay=60000
```

The problem is that with the info logs which I want to save in a file out of the jar.

```
log4j.appender.MAIN_LOG.File=log.log
```

Atm I use this but it makes nothing, I want to know what path I have to write here to make it write the files to a file at the same folder where the jar is located.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

```
log4j.appender.stdout.File=${user.home}/My Documents/abcFolder/logFile.log
```

This will save the jar in `My Documents`

Here is my config file

```
log4j.rootLogger= info, error, debug, stdout
#info, 

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender    
log4j.appender.stdout.File=${user.home}/My Documents/appFolder/applog.log
log4j.appender.stdout.MaxFileSize=2MB
log4j.appender.stdout.MaxBackupIndex=3
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender

# un-comment this if need to show log @ console
#log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
#log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out

log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%5p] %d{dd:MMM:yyyy:hh:mm:ss} (%F:%M:%L)%n%m%n%n
```